# Docker PHP: pthreads and fpm

Tags: php, docker, pthreads, zts

I have project running on Apache and PHP7 to handle web requests (UI, Forms, etc), it's build on Symfony components, if that makes any difference.

In addition to this, I have a console command that is using `pthreads` to sent emails concurrently (for speed reasons).

Would like to move the whole project on Docker (transitioning all other projects) and I'm not sure how to do that. There is a `php-zts` image variant, but that won't work with Nginx (or Apache).

One option I was considering is to have 2 separate php containers (one for fpm and one for zts), but I don't know how the fpm container will call a command on the zts container.

Any ideas/pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Although it's adding to the container count, you could implement a message queue (I've used RabbitMQ in docker) and the main container just puts tasks into a queue and the zts container sits and polls the queue and does the job.  Also means you can add multiple containers of either type to increase capacity.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll consider it. thank you